# Set "minifyEnabled" to "false" for external libraries only

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, minify

I have this error when I'm building the apk with an external library (SumUp)

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

Removing the library or setting "minifyEnabled" to "false" remove the error, but I don't want to do that.

How can I avoid shrinking only the external library?

I tried to modify the **proguard file** :

```
-keep class com.sumup.**
```

... with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your gradle build with the `-i` option to get more output and be able to solve your problem. Most likely ProGuard will output some warnings about the sumup library and fails to continue.

You can test this theory by adding `-ignorewarnings` to your proguard configuration file. It will probably succeeds, but you should take a look at the warnings as try to fix them.